# How do I compute dynamic key types for an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm getting started on Typescript and couldn't figure out how to set granular types on an object dynamically based on function input.

```js
    type Options<T1, T2> = {
        name: string;
        transforms: Record<string, {
            from: (val: T1) => T2,
            to: (val: T2) => T1,
        }>;
    };

    type IO<T> = {
        read:() => T;
        write: (value: T) => void;
    }

    function transformer<T1, T2>(options: Options<T1, T2>, value: T1) {
        const { name, transforms = {}} = options;

        // How do I type this as follows:
        //     - Has key `name` and return type `IO<T1>`
        //     - Transforms have key [dynamic name], and whatever IO<"return value of from">
        type Values = {
            [name/* exact value of name?? */]: IO<T1>,
            [FromReturnType<tr>/*??*/ in transforms]: IO<tr>,
        };

        const values: Values = {
            [name]: {
                read: () => value,
                write: (v) => value = v,
            },
        };

        for (const transform in transforms) {
            const { to, from } = transforms[transform];
            values[transform] = {
                read: () => from(value),
                write: (v) => value = to(v),
            };
        }

        return values;
    }
```

The consumer would then use the function as follows:

```js
    // Usage
    const { number, string, ...otherTypedTransforms } = transformer({
        name: "number",
        transforms: {
            string: {
                to: Number,
                from: String,
            },
            // Other transforms with different `from` types
            // ...
        },
    }, 0);
```

the hope is that tsc can infer `number.read()` as type `number` and `string.read()` as type `string` etc. based on the `from()` transform.

I've gone through many of the Q&As on SO but haven't been successful.

Comment: Can you provide an example with desired input and output types for your `transformer` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the typing I'd give to the `transformer()` call signature:

```
declare function transformer<K extends string, I, O extends object>(options: {
  name: K,
  transforms: { [P in keyof O]: { from: (val: I) => O[P], to: (val: O[P]) => I } }
}, value: I): { [P in keyof AddProp<O, K, I>]: IO<AddProp<O, K, I>[P]> };
    
type AddProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V> = Record<K, V> & T;
```

Before I explain it, let's just make sure that it does what you want with an example call:

```
const transformed = transformer({
  name: "number",
  transforms: {
    string: {
      to: Number,
      from: String,
    },
    date: {
      to: d => d.getTime(),
      from: (n: number) => new Date(n)
    }
  },
}, 0);
/* const transformed: {
    number: IO<number>;
    string: IO<string>;
    date: IO<Date>;
} */
```

Looks good, right?

---

So, the `transformer()` function is generic in three type parameters:

- `K extends string` is the type of the `name` filed of the `options` object.  This type parameter needs to be here so that you can keep track of the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) string value of `name`.  Otherwise, if you leave it as `string` as in your `Options` type, the compiler will forget it.
- `I` is the type of the `value` parameter, the input to every transform's `from()` method (and the output of its `to()` method).
- `O extends object` is an object whose properties are the keys of the `transforms` object, and whose values are the output of the corresponding transform's `from()` method (and the input of its `to()` method).  There will be no actual value of type `O` passed into `transformer()`, but the compiler will be able to infer it from `transforms`.  It is significantly easier to express both the `transforms` parameter and the function return type in terms of `O` than it is to express the return type in terms of the `transforms` parameter directly (which would involve various type queries).

The `transforms` property of the `options` object is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where we take each property key `P` of `O` and use its value type `O[P]` to construct the `from`/`to` method types.

For the return type of the function, we first augment `O` with a property whose key is type `K` and whose value is type `I`.  (I use the `AddProp` type function for this.)  And then we map that augmented type by taking each property and wrapping it with `IO<>`.

---

So that's the typing. As for the implementation, there's almost no chance that you could get the compiler to verify that it conforms to such a complex call signature.  And so the best way to proceed is to be very careful that you are implementing it properly, and use the equivalent of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress compiler errors.  In cases like this I tend to instead use an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with a single call signature of the desired typing, and whose implementation signature is significantly looser (using `any` liberally where necessary):

```
// call signature
function transformer<K extends string, I, O extends object>(options: {
  name: K,
  transforms: { [P in keyof O]: { from: (val: I) => O[P], to: (val: O[P]) => I } }
}, value: I): { [P in keyof AddProp<O, K, I>]: IO<AddProp<O, K, I>[P]> };

// implementation
function transformer(options: {
  name: string,
  transforms: Record<string, { from: (val: any) => any, to: (val: any) => any }>
}, value: any) {

  const { name, transforms = {} } = options;

  const values = {
    [name]: {
      read: () => value,
      write: (v: any) => value = v,
    },
  };

  for (const transform in transforms) {
    const { to, from } = transforms[transform];
    values[transform] = {
      read: () => from(value),
      write: (v) => value = to(v),
    };
  }

  return values;

}
```

And let's see that the compiler and the runtime agree, using the above test:

```
console.log(transformed.date.read().getFullYear()); // 1969
transformed.date.write(new Date());
console.log(transformed.number.read()); // 1627655089690 
console.log(transformed.string.read()); // "1627655089690"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkg8gHgCoD4oF4oG8BQUoBOEAhgCYBcUAFAJQZpIDceUA7gQJbASVUBuxADYBXHlCR10aPgHsOpZgF8cK0JCgBBUqQAKBGWGRQIAD24A7UgGcoMgEYArCAGNgAGigBpY2YiWbegYQBKCeECAeAGpomABKLjIEpAieUWgAZOLMOABmwuauHDLmUMAExOZWOYkAtsEpPhbWUFZlHOYA5h4wHnCNfs32Tq4oVAbARZWUuPjmxHWUqSxlFVW1VtNQANo6UO1QANbhMjlQcAC6mzn6NbwCgpQwkmhwO+cewDJ3QpSvOufPWBQRTAnCKDz3USPGibHZ7EpHEAnTTaQKGOAeVKwFCXWCILS6fTozHdFBvNCKbJ5AoTYqlcqVaoEOoEMZgWlTbAsOYLFptTpuZYMtbMjZQeLORLJVqcAXYKDXGS3aj3SgVECA9UfL4qn5QdWa8wgYEoMEQoRQ-VGui4FiSyrAeU8iAfYVMmo2TBYEEgzDjSZWbL4e2tKCQiCern4fBbZ24mbR-BEMi8QHhwWJ-DsLhifhq630MMW6CYPgZ6PgliUlT4JnUEOOlaM2rw+mrd1WG0sYPFUNYUoyDyKmrAjBt5uirZNkU1c7MRPhqxTt21c5jhOJ5MUaiA4f8Ys0cuJ7PcO5p4tjz78Q-d4Hz0EsIjAYQEEqL7LKHAN8cziCkS8rsywRUAmzqUAAROYwg1HYwTgeW04dtMt4yu0HTIZmA6UAActBsEEEe0bDpQADK-JdLelaJqQxCnlGmafJQ-5SFApAAHQdBAwBIBwdS0IRtY3Lw5iUFBMHBIC5gQKwUAACK0RAVDmDQlFVoK4JQAADDQzAAPQAFRQN+iG1H+GHRmJ+GPIglnBCg974KhnTWQgTkdPZt40XR8AIPJ3AeSC+m6SoIYyIIEBsYIMgdFQJlAexXkRVutAcVxABiwiCIIACaJCsjQOlQLpulQAAjAAnAAbOVOBxXUCUKWxJ6KVJMl+YpBXMKF4WRdFsWAfVbG2QQbHJZ1RUlaVlUAEwAOyVQArAtmkABxVeVmlQF+vZhRFUUxXVf5sW5o0kKQtCFcVUDgVNc2Lcta3VZp4EqEAA)

Comment: Typescript seems to play better with `Record<string, unknown>` instead of `object`. Everything else types well.

Comment: Can you explain how it “plays better”?  Just wondering.

Comment: I believe you're the one who opened this issue, right? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732. Just helping TSC narrow in on types better.

Comment: I thought that might be it: [my thoughts on that, if it matters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640)